# GREP function from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python

I have a python script I wrote that I need to port to php. It recursively searches a given directory and builds a string based on regex searches. The first function I am trying to port is below. It takes a regex and a base dir, recursively searches all files in that dir for the regex, and builds a list of the string matches.

```
def grep(regex, base_dir):
    matches = list()
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
        for filename in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
                matches = matches + re.findall(regex, content)
    return matches
```

I never use PHP except for basic GET param manipulation. I grabbed some directory walking code from the web, and am struggling to make it work like the python function above due to my utter lack of the php API.

```
function findFiles($dir = '.', $pattern = '/./'){
  $prefix = $dir . '/';
  $dir = dir($dir);
  while (false !== ($file = $dir->read())){
    if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') continue;
    $file = $prefix . $file;
    if (is_dir($file)) findFiles($file, $pattern);
    if (preg_match($pattern, $file)){
      echo $file . "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why not simply use grep at the cli? `grep -d recurse 'your string'`?

Comment: Take a look at [glob()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: I am hitting this php script via an http request and need the returned values in a certain format, so regular grep won't work. Will check out glob()=.

Comment: @JohnConde: Does `glob()` recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: @JohnConde: Also, looks like glob() returns an array of the files, I need the actual matches.

Comment: What's wrong with using Python for "some basic GET param manipulation," thus removing the need to port it PHP altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
<?php 

class FileGrep {
    private $dirs;      // Scanned directories list
    private $files;     // Found files list
    private $matches;   // Matches list

    function __construct() {
        $this->dirs = array();
        $this->files = array();
        $this->matches = array();
    }

    function findFiles($path, $recursive = TRUE) {
        $this->dirs[] = realpath($path);
        foreach (scandir($path) as $file) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
                $fullname = realpath("{$path}/{$file}");
                if (is_dir($fullname) && !is_link($fullname) && $recursive) {
                    if (!in_array($fullname, $this->dirs)) {
                        $this->findFiles($fullname, $recursive);
                    }
                } else if (is_file($fullname)){
                    $this->files[] = $fullname;
                }
            }
        }
        return($this->files);
    }

    function searchFiles($pattern) {
        $this->matches = array();
        foreach ($this->files as $file) {
            if ($contents = file_get_contents($file)) {
                if (preg_match($pattern, $contents, $matches) > 0) {
                    //echo $file."\n";
                    $this->matches = array_merge($this->matches, $matches);
                }
            }
        }
        return($this->matches);
    }
}


// Usage example:

$fg = new FileGrep();
$files = $fg->findFiles('.');               // List all the files in current directory and its subdirectories
$matches = $fg->searchFiles('/open/');      // Search for the "open" string in all those files

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <pre><?php print_r($matches) ?></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Be aware that:

- It reads each file to search for the pattern, so it may require a lot of memory (check the "memory_limit" configuration in your PHP.INI file).
- It does'nt work with unicode files. If you are working with unicode files you should use the "mb_ereg_match" function rather than the "preg_match" function.
- It does'nt follow symbolic links

In conclusion, even if it's not the most efficient solution at all, it should work.